# & doesn't work for long equation in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Anyone can figure out what is wrong with these lines in Fortran :

```
if (i==1) then
    u(i,j+1)=u(i,j)-c*dt/2/dx*(u(i+1,j)-u(imax-1,j)) &
    + (c*c*dt*dt)/2/dx/dx*(u(i+1,j)-2*u(i,j)+u(imax-1,j))
```

more codes here:

```
      select case (case_no)
C.. 1--Lax Wendroff one step scheme
      case (1)
          write (6,*) 'Entrance for the Lax-Wendroff one step method'
          t=dt            
          do while (t<=18)
              do i=1,41
                  if (i==1) then
                      u(i,j+1)=u(i,j)-c*dt/2/dx*(u(i+1,j)-u(imax-1,j))    &
                      + c*c*dt*dt/2/dx/dx*(u(i+1,j)-2*u(i,j)    &
                      + u(imax-1,j))
                  else if (i==41) then
                      u(i,j+1)=u(i,j)-c*dt/2/dx*(u(i+1,j)-u(i-1,2))    &  
                      + c*c*dt*dt/2/dx/dx*(u(i+1,j)-2*u(i,j)    &
                      + u(i-1,2))
                  else 
                      u(i,j+1)=u(i,j)-c*dt/2/dx*(u(i+1,j)-u(i-1,j))    & 
                      + c*c*dt*dt/2/dx/dx*(u(i+1,j)-2*u(i,j)    & 
                      +u(i-1,j))
                  end if 
                  j=j+1
                  t=t+dt
              end do
          end do
```

Equation is too long and I wanna use '&' to separate it into two lines. But the compiler said
1. classifiable statement at 'u(i,j+1)'
2. invalid character in name at '+'

I am new to Fortran. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that the compiler said *1. classifiable statement at 'u(i,j+1)'*  I expect it said *1. unclassifiable statement at 'u(i,j+1)'*  Please format your code correctly and report error messages accurately.  The former point is most important in this case as the cause of the error may be bad formatting.

Comment: OK, i have done that.

Comment: The line looks okay to me, could you add a few more lines around it? Also, what column is `+` located in? How are you compiling this? And with what compiler?

Comment: I believe it is because lines are too long. I have tried + in same colomn as u(i,j+1) and =, doesn't work. I use gfortran as compiler.

Comment: I have added more codes in question.

Comment: Are the lines longer than 132 characters so that they are truncated?  Try `-Wline-truncation` with gfortran.  Full list of my recommended debugging options for gfortran: `-fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace`.

Comment: The lines are less than 132 after using '&'

Comment: well, being stumped the first thing i'd do is move those lines all the way to the left and get rid of the continuation (the whole expression is < 132 char ). After you make it work worry about line wrapping to make it look nice

Comment: Is the file saved with a `.f` suffix or `.f90`? And, again, what command are you using to compile this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have fixed form source features (you are using a C in column one to start comments) but you are asking about free form line continuation.  You need to decide which source form you are using (free form is best in the absence of a need to remain consistent with ancient code), tell the compiler that you are using free form in the appropriate manner (typically using a .f90 file extension) and then make sure that the comment style, token splitting and line continuation aspects are consistent with that form.