# Breaking long logical statements in multiple lines in fortran?

Tags: fortran, abaqus

Hi I wrote the following code for the Abaqus which is linked with fortran but this showed me several syntax error and not getting compiled. How can I fix the code so that it compiles?

```
 if(noel.le.1150.or.noel.ge.1201.and.noel.le.2350.or.noel.ge.2811.and.noel.le.8100.or.noel.ge.8331.and.noel.le.13620.or.noel.ge.14081.and.noel.le.19370.or.noel.ge.19601) 
  then
 ...action>>>
 end if
```

Comment: Other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133324/continuation-in-gfortran-5-2-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789762/doesnt-work-for-long-equation-in-fortran

Comment: you shouldn't need to do that in Abaqus. make a seperate section with those elements, and use the name of the material whcih is passed into the routine to do your logical tests

Answer (score 3):

with gfortran (assuming free form), one might use the switch `-ffree-line-length-none` to enable arbitrarily long input lines, or use "line continuation" as:

```
PROGRAM test

  INTEGER :: x = 1200

  IF( &
    x .LE. 1150 &
    .OR.  &
    (x .GE. 1201 .AND. x .LE. 2350) &
    .OR. &
    (x .GE. 2811 .AND. x .LE. 8100) &
  ) THEN
    WRITE(*, *) "OK"
  ELSE
    WRITE(*, *) "KO"
  END IF

END PROGRAM
```